# MySQL: How do I relate multiple tables together

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the least expensive `guitarRig`. Guitar rigs have parts (I.e. `amplifier`, `cabinet`, `microphone`, `guitarType`, `guitarStringType`, `patchCord`, `effectsPedal`) which come from products. 
Products are purchased for a price as dictated by my `PurchaseInformation` table.

Here are my tables:

```
Table Part:
    name
    guitarRig references GuitarRig(name)
    product references Product(name)

Table Product:
    name
    part references Part(name)
    barcodeNumber

Table PurchaseInformation:
    price
    product references Product(name)    
    purchasedFrom references Store(name)
```

---

So far what I have is this:

```
SELECT guitarRig
FROM Part
WHERE product =
(
    SELECT name
    FROM Product
    WHERE name =
    (
        SELECT product, MIN(price) as minPrice
        FROM PurchaseInformation
        GROUP BY minPrice
    )
);
```

I realize this has a number of problems with this (i.e. I'm trying to say `name` is equal to two columns, `product` and `minPrice`), however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so there may be some typos. My assumption is that the cheapest guitarRig is determined by summing all the part prices for that rig.

```
SELECT p.guitarRig
     , sum(r.price) as totPrice
  FROM Part p
     , Product r
     , PurchaseInformation i
 WHERE p.product = r.name
   AND p.name    = r.part
   AND r.name    = i.product
GROUP BY p.guitarRig
ORDER BY totPrice desc 
LIMIT 1
```